# use of the preposition "in" in front of here/there

Tags: difference

I want to know if there is any difference of meaning between the following two sentences:

> 1- It is hot here/there. 
>  
>   2- It is hot in here/there.

Comment: This is obviously not a proofreading question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expressions are used to mean that it's hot where you are, with the following nuances:

(1) **here** is used for the climate of a city or country:

> This is Maine. It's too hot here to grow oranges!

(2) **In here** is used for any building or enclosure that you're in:

> I'm sorry it's so hot in here - I'm baking a turkey.

(3) **in here** is used to contrast the interior from the exterior:

> It's freezing out today, but it's nice and hot in here.

(4) **It's (a little) hot in here** can be a subtle (and convenient) hint when you want someone to turn up the air-conditioning without telling them to do so outright. I live in Florida, where this is very useful, but this may be foreign to most. Similiary, when visiting a friend, he might ask you (the guest) "Is it hot in here?" meaning *Would you like me to turn up the ac?*

NOTE that (1) and (2) can both be expressed with simply "here" - so even if you're in an enclosure, you can say "it's hot here."

Answer (score 0):

"It's hot in here" means roughly "It's hot in this building" or "It's hot in this room" (or "It's hot in this tent" or "It's hot in this cave" . . . you get the idea), whereas "It's hot here" more likely means something like "It's hot in this part of the country."

Comment: Why *it's hot here* won't work for the tent since *here* also specifies the place i.e. the tent?

Comment: @MaulikV You can. But be aware that you can use it this way ("It is hot here" to specify either a region or a specific location) but not the reverse - you would not use "It's hot in here" to describe the weather of a region.  (@CocoPop's answer refers to this too.)