# Where to use 'in here' and ' in there'

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request

So far as I know 'here' and 'there' are adverbs.
I always listen 'in here' and 'in there'
Are the phrases correct?

Comment: Yes, they're fine. As for meaning, does [this post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30867/use-of-the-preposition-in-in-front-of-here-there) help?

Comment: @OP - could you give a few examples of how you'd use "in here" and "in there"? Note that "here/there" could be used with other prepositions too "Place it _over there_", "Come _over here_", etc. Its not limited to just "in".

Comment: He's working in there. We're discussing an issue in here.

Comment: Abu, that's still not enough context. If I am in the kitchen and you are in the bathroom taking a shower, and someone asks me, "Where is Abu?" I could say, "He is washing in here" and that would be ***wrong***, or I could say, "He is washing in there," and that would be fine. We don't know if the phrases are correct unless we know what you are trying to say. (Grammatically, however, they are fine.) P.S. please clarify by editing your question, not by adding another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the difference between

> in here

and

> in there

is the distance that the referred location is to the speaker.

*Here* for close, *there* for further away.

> *over here*
>   She lives *over here*, she is my neighbor.

means some area close to the speaker

> *over there*
>   She lives *over there* about a mile down the road.

can be anywhere else.

Comment: When to say ' out there', ' out now'

Comment: Those are two completely different phrases *there* is a location, *now* is a  point in time. *Out there* usually means an area away from the speaker, "There are many galaxies *out there*." in the distance. *Out now* means *leave immediately*, "Get out now!".